# Windows 10 iot-core: where are the DEBUG output logfiles from my headless App?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have an iot-core UWP headless app that runs fine when deployed via VisualStudio 2015 onto an RPi. Now I build a custom image/FFU and deploy that, and the app crashes. I'm trying to figure out how to debug this. Since the Visual Studio debug-stubs are not present in custom image (although my app is a debug-mode binary), I cannot attach the VisualStudio debugger.

I looked here C$\Data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive*.wer on the iot-core machine but its (text) contents did not help a whole lot aside from confirming a crash.

I'm now searching for my the DEBUG output from my App itself. Does anybody know where this is or how to enable it?

Comment: I am thinking if you have COM port available on your device, you may consider serial port debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device Portal is an easy-to-use tool to view debug log files of your app. You can specify your event sources using the list of providers and view event information by the event viewer. There are plenty providers that will assist you with locating your app's problem. You can see part of them in this picture:

[image]

You can follow [this introduction](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/10/using-device-portal-to-view-debug-logs-for-uwp/#48OGVZ4kALylkhFE.97) to try to use it.

In addition, you can use [Windbg](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/windbg). It is relatively complicated. You can start from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt219729(v=vs.85).aspx). There is a article about [debugging application crash with Windbg](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/707488/Part-Windows-Debugging-Techniques-Debugging-Ap) that you can reference.